# Getting text and select box on single line

Tags: css

What CSS trick is necessary to get the text and following Select box on a single line?

How cn I control the specifics (height, weight) for that particular select box

Its about the text and Select at the top of the right-sidebar:
"within" and the following select box for the distance.

[See this page in action](http://nederland.dansen.nl)

Comment: `display: inline-block;` will give you what you need. [read that](http://robertnyman.com/2010/02/24/css-display-inline-block-why-it-rocks-and-why-it-sucks/)

Comment: instead of posting the whole page, create a custom Fiddle that shows only the relevant code (markup + CSS).

Answer (score 0):

Add `display: inline-block` to the two elements you wish to be side by side. Then ensure you have the width within their container to accept them side by side. In this case I added `display: inline-block` the the elements below and then set their width accordingly.

```
#top label {
display: inline-block;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 12px;
}

.main_color select {
display: inline-block;
border-color: #e1e1e1;
background-color: #fcfcfc;
color: #919191;
width: 170px;
}
```

Comment: This does not change anything to my layout :(

Comment: i applied the CSS in my answere within chrome dev tools and it worked perfectly